# c# regex adding in caret and dollar sign

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex:

```
TEST_(\d{4}).xml.gz
```

Which should match a string of the following format:

```
TEST_2015.xml.gz
```

and I am sure this works as I have run it through a Regex tester, and it returns a match in my C# file.

This regex will also match

```
sTEST_2015.xml.gz
```

OR

```
TEST_2015.xml.gzc
```

etc

Which is not what I want.

So I add

```
^TEST_(\d{4}).xml.gz$
```

Which will now match as I want.

All fine so far.

My problem is, when I try and add this to a C# Regex match, the pattern no longer matches, as below:

```
var FileNameRegex = new Regex(@"^TEST_(\d{4}).xml.gz$");
```

I have also tried:

```
var FileNameRegex = new Regex(@"(^)TEST_(\d{4}).xml.gz($)");

var FileNameRegex = new Regex(@"^(TEST_(\d{4}).xml.gz)$");

var FileNameRegex = new Regex(@"\^TEST_(\d{4}).xml.gz\$");
```

etc, but they are not working.

What am I missing.

I have looked on google and SO, and have found questions relating to these symbols in C#, but none of the solutions I have found have solved my problem.

??

Here is a the full program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sReconciliationFileFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReconciliationFileLocation"];
    DirectoryInfo sReconciliationFileDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(sReconciliationFileFolder);

    foreach (var Reconciliationfile in sReconciliationFileDirectory.GetFiles("*.gz"))
    {
        var FileNameRegex = new Regex(@"^TEST_(\d{4}).xml.gz$");
        Match validFileName = FileNameRegex.Match(Reconciliationfile.FullName);

        if (validFileName.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Reconciliationfile.FullName);

        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("FINISHED");
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Please note, if I remove the ^ and $, the console writes the file names in the folder

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. You're showing us the code to *create* a `Regex` option, but not what you're then calling on it.

Comment: Wild guess is upper/lower case mix in filenames - but can't be sure until you give some sample filenames.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have posted the full code

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov if you put that as the answer I will mark it as correct

Comment: Please note that if you'd provided the full example with sample input and output (which doesn't need to be from `GetFiles` - if you'd looked at the value you were passing into `FileNameRegex.Match` you could have provided an exact example as sample input) you would have received an answer earlier... or quite possibly figured it out yourself while constructing the example. Worth remembering for next time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `Reconciliationfile.Name`. Currently you use `Reconciliationfile.FullName` which gives you **full path** for the file.

Also in regex you have to escape `.`, it should be `@"^TEST_\d{4}\.xml\.gz$"`